# what is the use of 下 in this sentence

Tags: grammar

I was wondering how した is used in this sentence.

> また ああやって　くだらないバカな　斜め下すぎる解決法　出して

I pretty much know everything else about it, but I don't know how 斜め and 下 work together.

Answer (score 2):

**斜め下** is a fixed word.

I think it was originally used in a set phrase 予想の斜め上／下, where 予想の上／下 means "higher/lower than expectation", and 斜め is added to mean "from an unsuspected direction".

Thus 斜め上 started to describe that something (someone's action, idea, or some courses of event) is so shockingly unexpected, beyond the range of ordinary imagination that you feel as if caught off guard. Then by analogy, 斜め下 to mean its less-than-expected counterpart, that is something so eccentrically silly that even a foolproof measure couldn't prevent it.